# Deleteing cancelled orders

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-status

I wanted to delete the test and cancelled orders from magento but all the codes I found didn't work on 1.9.0 and onwards. So on test site I deleted those orders through phpmyadmin. Is that the correct way?

```
DELETE FROM sql_flat_rate
WHERE order_id=1;
```

The script I tried was this one:

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
//replace your own orders numbers here:
$test_order_ids = [
    '100000001',
    '100000002',
    '100000003',
    '100000111',
    '100000112',
    '100000199',
];
foreach ($test_order_ids as $id) {
    try {
        Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id)->delete();
        echo "order #" . $id . " is removed" . PHP_EOL;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "order #" . $id . " could not be remvoved: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
echo "complete."
```

Comment: did you tried [link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/orders-eraser.html) & [link2](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html)

Comment: I did not. Should I prefer this over what I am actually doing? If so, any reason for it.

Comment: I dont have much idea from technical point of view, but dont you think it will be easy if there is an option from backend only instead of going to phpmyadmin and doing this, try above extensions in demo site if it works for you, thats better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are confident that you are able to delete directly from database (with all related tables also), then you can go for deletion via phpmyadmin directly.

By using script, you will always need to modify your file whenever you would like to delete more orders.

So I would suggest to use any good extension to delete orders, because it will provide you facility to see which orders you are going to delete from admin panel directly.

Below are some extensions:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-6.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delete-orders-9-1.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete not only orders but also accompanying information you need to significantly expand your code. This information is also used by other modules and it takes additional space, time and could lead to different errors. Here is the example of the working code that deletes orders, quotes, quote items, payments, addresses and everything else:

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
//replace your own orders numbers here:
$test_order_ids = [
    '100000055',
    '100000056', // this order does not exist
    '100000076',
    '200000020',
    '200000021',
    '200000022',
    '200000023',
    '200000024',
    '200000025',
    '200000026',
    '200000027',
    '200000028',
];
foreach ($test_order_ids as $id) {
    try {
        /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order */
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id);
        if (!is_object($order) || !$order->getId()) {
            continue;
        }

        $order->cancel()->save();
        deleteOrderCompletely($order);

        echo "order #" . $id . " is removed" . PHP_EOL;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "order #" . $id . " could not be remvoved: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

echo "complete.";
Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');

function deleteOrderCompletely(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
{
    /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Resource $coreResource */
    $coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $write = $coreResource->getConnection('core_write');
    $orderId = $order->getId();

    // delete
    if ($order->getQuoteId()) {
        $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_quote') . "` WHERE `entity_id`=" . $order->getQuoteId());
        $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_quote_address') . "` WHERE `quote_id`=" . $order->getQuoteId());
        $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_quote_item') . "` WHERE `quote_id`=" . $order->getQuoteId());
        $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_quote_payment') . "` WHERE `quote_id`=" . $order->getQuoteId());
    }

    $order->delete();

    $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_grid') . "` WHERE `entity_id`=" . $orderId);
    $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_address') . "` WHERE `parent_id`=" . $orderId);
    $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_item') . "` WHERE `order_id`=" . $orderId);
    $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_payment') . "` WHERE `parent_id`=" . $orderId);
    $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_payment_transaction') . "` WHERE `order_id`=" . $orderId);
    $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_order_status_history') . "` WHERE `parent_id`=" . $orderId);

    $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_invoice') . "` WHERE `order_id`=" . $orderId);
    $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_creditmemo') . "` WHERE `order_id`=" . $orderId);
    $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_flat_shipment') . "` WHERE `order_id`=" . $orderId);
    $write->query("DELETE FROM `" . $coreResource->getTableName('sales_order_tax') . "` WHERE `order_id`=" . $orderId);
}
```

Here is the result of its applying on our server:

[image]

You should pay attention to errors that can cancel interrupt work. You can modify this code and make it more Magento-like but this will take additional time.